# Parent element layout w.r.t. bounding box of rotated element

Tags: html, css

I want to rotate text in a table header 90 degrees (imho a sensible use case), however `transform: rotate(-90.0deg);` does not behave nicely regarding lay-outing. That is, the parent element adjusts it's height to the height of the child, which after rotation is the width. This is annoying since this mostly makes the child element to significantly overflow the parent, causing text to overlap other text.

### Example ( https://jsfiddle.net/jpe3voxy/ )

```
<div id="z">
  A very long header
</div>
<div id="a">
  <div id="b">
    Hello World
  </div>
</div>
```

```
#a {
  background-color: blue
}

#b {
  background-color: red;
  transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 50px; width: 200px;
}
```

Element `#b` overlaps the header. One can solve this by adding translation transforms on `#b` and enforcing specific sizes on `#a`. In other words, manual layouting, and that is messy and will not work in general for dynamic content of `#b`.

**Question** How can I make the parent element layout w.r.t. the bounding-box of the child element, instead of the  untransformed size of the child element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And idea would be to consider adding margin to the transformed element so that its height + the margin be equal to its width then adjust the transform-origin:

```css
#a {
  background-color: blue;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#b {
  background-color: red;
  transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(-90.0deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom:calc(200px - 50px);
  transform-origin:top right;
}
```

```html
<div id="z">
  A very long header
</div>
<div id="a">
  <div id="b">
    Hello World
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, this mimics a translation via the margin, which is manual layouting instead of something generic that adjusts to the amount of text in the cell. Moreover, the child is shifted to the right.

Comment: @Herbert it doesn't exaclt mimic .. but since you have fixed width/height for your element you can easily adjust the margin also ... if everything is dynamic, I am afraid you won't find a generic solution ... the shift you can control it using transform origin. You want it to stick to the left side ?

Comment: I want a solution for table headers, in general they should go left to right, so yes, stick to the left

Comment: @Herbert updated ;) in this case you need to add a 100% translation before rotating

Comment: It's still messy, but I'll accept it, since I guess CSS doesn't offer anything better. Thanks!